# How to parse my CSV file?

Tags: ios, swift, csv

This is the first time I am trying to parse a CSV file; I have only worked with JSON files before. I understand that CSV is an abbreviation for comma separated values. I have a CSV file with a list of all rest stops on interstate highways across the United States; however, the values in this file are not separated by a comma. I was wondering if anyone could help me parse this file into object? My aim is to sort through this file and put each interstate belonging to a particular state in the corresponding object(state). For instance Interstate 5 (I-5) spans the entire western coast of the U.S. it starts from the Canadian border and goes through Washington, Oregon, and California all the way to the Mexican border. Consequently, I-5 should be in the "Washington", "Oregon", and "California" objects. The code below is my attempt to remove all punctuation and replace them with only a comma to get a regular CSV file. Sequentially, after I have created a regular CSV file I try to sort as explained above. This is my code:

```
var californiaInterstates: [InterstateAttributes] = []
func parseCSVFile(){
        var fullString: String = ""
        var restStops: [String] = []
        guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Rest_Areas", ofType: "csv") else{
            print("There was an error parsing the data file!")
            return
        }
        do{
            fullString = try String(contentsOfFile: path)
        }catch let error as NSError{
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }
        restStops = fullString.componentsSeparatedByString("\r")
        for (index, restStop) in restStops.enumerate() {
            let element = restStop.componentsSeparatedByString("\"").joinWithSeparator("").componentsSeparatedByString("]").joinWithSeparator("").componentsSeparatedByString("[").joinWithSeparator("").componentsSeparatedByString("|").joinWithSeparator(",")
            restStops[index] = element
        }
        for (index, restStop) in restStops.enumerate(){
            //print(index)
            let restStopArray = restStop.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
            if restStopArray[2] == "CA" {
                let interstateAttributes = InterstateAttributes()
                interstateAttributes.latitude = Double(restStopArray[0])
                interstateAttributes.longitude = Double(restStopArray[1])
                interstateAttributes.state = restStopArray[2]
                interstateAttributes.interstate = restStopArray[3]
                interstateAttributes.bound = restStopArray[4]
                interstateAttributes.description = restStopArray[5]
                interstateAttributes.name = restStopArray[6]
                interstateAttributes.RR = restStopArray[7]
                interstateAttributes.PT = restStopArray[8]
                interstateAttributes.VM = restStopArray[9]
                interstateAttributes.pets = restStopArray[10]
                interstateAttributes.HF = restStopArray[11]
                interstateAttributes.RVDump = restStopArray[12]
                californiaInterstates.append(interstateAttributes)
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried to sort the highways in California as an example. This code does not work and gives an error because some of the indexes are out of range when I try to access interstate attributes. Can you please help me parse and sort this CVS file?

Attached is the CSV file:

[RestAreasCombined_USA.csv](http://filenurse.com/download/005c1746b25fe3605fb5ac633afe6c6a.html)

If you have any trouble downloading the file please let me know.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read my post!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that this is not completely a .csv file.  The "Details" column, column 4, is just a string that (unfortunately for you) may contain commas itself.

What you need to do is expect the first 3 columns to be there and then do more parsing of the sub items.

For example, the interstate item is not a separate field; it's part of the type notes column, column 3 (and is not guaranteed to be an interstate; look at rows 14 and 22, for example, relating to US highways).

Also, why are you testing the third column for "CA"?  None of the rows in the file you linked have that at all...

And then, when you get to string entries 4- length, you are going to have to just test them against "RR", "PT", "VM", "Pets", "HF", "Gas", Food", "RV Dump", etc. to set the appropriate boolean values for your exit.

Comment: I am checking for "CA" because the third index is always an abbreviation for the state name. For instance CA is for California. This is an example of an entry: -120.780655,36.860709,CA,I-5,NB,JOHN ERRECA REST AREA, MM386,RR,PT,VM,Pets,HF,PHONES

Comment: That entry does not match the CSV file you linked.

    `Longitude,Latitude,TYPE_NOTES,DETAILS
-67.834062,46.141129,REST AREA-FOLLOW SIGNS SB I-95 MM305,"RR, PT, Pets, HF"
-67.845906,46.138084,REST AREA-FOLLOW SIGNS NB I-95 MM305,"RR, PT, Pets, HF"
-68.498471,45.659781,TURNOUT NB I-95 MM249,Scenic Vista-NO FACILITIES
-68.534061,45.598464,REST AREA SB I-95 MM240,"RR, PT, Pets, HF"
-68.539034,45.594001,REST AREA NB I-95 MM240,"RR, PT, Pets, HF"`

Not a "CA" to be seen.

Comment: You still have the same problem.  What you have here is not just a list of comma separated values.  Instead, what you have is:

1) comma separated:  long, lat; then one more comma;
2) quote to open, then comma separated state, interstate or highway, name, mile marker, close quote, then one more comma;
3) quote to open, then bracket, comma-separated list of items that may or may not be present, then bracket, then pipe, optional elements, then close quote.

You are going to have to do multiple levels of parsing.  I would recommend splitting tokens first by quote and then by comma.